# CSS: Having 3 div on the same line with the middle one taking the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I'm building a toolbar, I'd like the yellow part in the following example to take the whole space left (in white):

http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/1/

```
<div class="left"> Some content </div>
<span class="middle"> This should fill the space left </span>
<div class="right"> Some other content </div>
```

with css:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Edit: the content of left and right is dynamic, it can change, so I don't want to set width on them**

Comment: middle is not div its span.

Comment: what widths are the left and right?

Comment: @Pete it's dynamic it can change

Comment: It's worth noting here that `floated` elements are treated as `block` display elements. So setting both float *and* display properties on the same element is pointless unless the display is set to `none`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if that suits you because of a slight HTML change:

```
<div class="left"> Some content </div>
<div class="right"> Some other content </div>
<span class="middle"> This should fill the space </span>
```

But I believe it is what you want,

CSS:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/MWjGH/12/

Comment: No need for the `display: inline-block;` on those floated elements. Floated elements are treated as `display: block;` regardless.

Comment: Ok sorry for changing mind again, but this is the right answer. see http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/18/

Comment: `overflow: hidden` actually changes the shape of its element's contents? Huh. I've learned something today.

Answer (score 6):

Put the middle div after the floated divs:

```
<div class="left"> Some content </div>
<div class="right"> Some other content </div>
<div class="middle"> This should fill the space left </div>
```

Then, don't change any of the `display` properties so they stay on `block` (the default for `div`)

```
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLmj7/

Comment: Fixed and added working fiddle. Sorry for the hurried first attempt. Missed the `inline-block`s.

Comment: perfect answer, I knew it must have been something that simple.

Comment: @plus-: you do realise that with this if the middle content is taller than the sidebars then it will escape the boundary? Is this actually what you're after here? http://jsfiddle.net/hLmj7/2/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes that's fine

Comment: @plus-: I see, you should have specified this in the question. This answer doesn't really fit the question all that well.

Answer (score 3):

If you do't have a fixed width for the two side columns, you can always `display:table-cell`.

```
.left {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: table-cell;
}
.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
.right {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/5/).

With this you're then able to add `min-width` to the outer columns without having to keep changing the width of the middle element.

[JSFiddle example with `min-width` applied](http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/8/).

Comment: Ok this is actually the answer I needed: See http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/14/ with added borders whereas the previous accepted answer gives http://jsfiddle.net/hLmj7/3/

Comment: Your right and left divs will grow with the middle one though, and vice versa: http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/16/

Comment: If that isn't the desired effect then [xpy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15428338/1317805) would be most relevant.

Comment: @JamesDonelly that's exact

Answer (score 0):

try this:

don't right align your last div

make all your containers `float:left`

and give percentage width to each of your containers, so that their total sum should be 100%;

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/MWjGH/7/)

if you don't want to enforce a static width do this:

give each of your containers a `width:auto`, but be notified, that,

if the total sum of the width of each of the containers turns out to be more than that of parent( body in your case) contaienr, then line-break would occur, 
a div will slide down to the next row.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/MWjGH/11/)

Comment: I don't want to enforce width, the content of left and right can change

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your divs in a wrapper, and assign the background-color to the wrapper div
Then, you don't need to specify width at all.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWjGH/4/)

Html:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="left"> Some content </div>
    <div class="middle"> This should fill the space left </div>
    <div class="right"> Some other content </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toolbar {
    background-color: yellow;    
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
.middle {
    display: inline-block;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Consider adding clearfix to the wrapper div as the divs inside are floating :)

Comment: the background of the middle element is more complex, it contains border and all and can't be applied to the wrapper

Comment: yep, in that case `display: table-cell;` or `table/tr/td` are the ways to go!