# 2 Sidebars (Left & Right Fixed Witdh) and fluid content

Tags: html, css

what i want is if is possible to make 2 sidebars with fixed witdh and fluid content !
for example i will use hide & show sidebar ... and after i hide left or right , content to be fluid !

```css
    /* Middle
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    .middle2 {

      /* border-left: 290px solid #B5E3FF; */

      /* border-right: 290px solid #FFACAA; */

      position: relative;

    }

    .middle2:after {

      display: table;

      clear: both;

      content: '';

    }

    .container2 {

      width: 100%;

      float: left;

      overflow: hidden;

      margin-right: -100%;

    }

    .content2 {

      /* padding: 0 20px; */

    }

    /* Left Sidebar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    .left-sidebar {

      float: left;

      width: 290px;

      position: relative;

      background: #B5E3FF;

      /* left: -290px; */

    }

    /* Right Sidebar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    .right-sidebar {

      float: right;

      /* margin-right: -290px; */

      width: 290px;

      position: relative;

      background: #FFACAA;

    }

    .wrapper {

      width: 993px;

      margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle2">
    <div class="container2">
      <aside class="left-sidebar">
        asd</aside>
      <main class="content2">
      </main>
      <!-- .content -->

      <aside class="right-sidebar">
        asd</aside>
    </div>
    <!-- .container-->
  </div>
</div>
```

i dont know why but not works for me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428122/css-having-3-div-on-the-same-line-with-the-middle-one-taking-the-remaining-spac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something similar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.middle-content {
   display: block;
}

.left {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
}

.right {
   background-color: red;
   width: 200px;
   float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <aside class="left">
      Left Bar
    </aside>
    <aside class="right">
      Right Bar
    </aside>
    <div class="middle-content">
      Content
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/j75x4Lqm/

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox really solves this problem for you and is pretty widely supported (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). If you haven't used it before, CSS-Tricks has a pretty decent explanation of its properties and implementation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've simplified your CSS a bit and, I believe, gotten the result you wanted here: http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/MyJGzN?editors=0100

You will need to add `display:flex` to the parent container and, if you want the sidebars to always be 290px, prevent them from growing and shrinking via `flex:0 0 auto`. The `main` will then take up all the other space.